# I am trying to setup swagger with node js but I am not able to see the output API in browser

Tags: swagger

I set up swagger with node as can be seen in code 1, though I am able to see the output

[image]

but i am not able to see get api in the browser.

here is my code.

```
project structure:
      swagger:
        server.js------------------>code 1
        package.json.
        package-lock.json.
        api:
          routes:
              user.js----------------> code 2


code-2)
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();
//const path=require('path');

/** 
* @swagger
* /users:
*  get:
*   description: use to request all users
*   response:
*    '200':
*       description:successful response
*/
routes.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "handling get requests"
    });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

code-1)

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express')
const userroute = require('./api/routes/user.js');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const path = require('path');
//routes
app.use('/users', userroute);



const swaggerjsdoc = require('swagger-jsdoc')
const swaggerui = require('swagger-ui-express')
//Extended: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/#infoObject
const swaggeroption = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
        info: {
            title: 'user API',
            description: 'get API for user details by Id',
            contact: {
                name: "amazing developer"
            },

        },
        servers: ["http://localhost:3000"]

    },
    apis: [path.join(process.cwd(), "api/routes/abc.js")]
};

const swaggerdocs = swaggerjsdoc(swaggeroption);

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerui.serve, swaggerui.setup(swaggerdocs));

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server started swagger");
})
```

Comment: Hi! I guess 'api/routes/abc.js' is actually 'api/routes/user.js' or whatever filename `code-2` is stored in. correct?

Comment: ohh my goshhhh,, How could I not see that :(,,,,, thanks bro, thanks a lot